# Бесконечная загрузка при использовании метода sync Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, nginx

Подскажите пожалуйста, я пытаюсь обновить связи моделей многие ко многим с помощью метода sync, но выполнение проваливается до максимального времени выполнения скрипта.

Миграция связующей таблицы

```
Schema::create('lot_trading_manager', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('lot_id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('trading_manger_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('lot_id')->references('id')->on('lots')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('trading_manger_id')->references('id')->on('trading_managers')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Связи модели Lot

```
public function tradingManagers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(TradingManager::class, 'lot_trading_manager', 'lot_id', 'trading_manger_id');
}
```

Модели TradingManager

```
public function lots()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Lot::class, 'lot_trading_manager', 'trading_manger_id', 'lot_id');
}
```

Сама синхронизация выполнена в следующем методе

```
private function syncLotTradingManagers($lot, $request)
{

    if (! $request->organizer_id && ! $request->arbitrator_id) return;

    if ( isset($request->organizer_id) ) $ids[] = $request->organizer_id;
    if ( isset($request->arbitrator_id) ) $ids[] = $request->arbitrator_id;

    $lot->tradingManagers()->sync($ids);
}
```

Так вот в итоге если обновить страницу то данные синхронизируются, но почему php виснет до максимального времени выполнения скрипта я не знаю, в этом собственно и вопрос.

Используется:
Laravel последней версии
nginx:1.17.8
php 7.4
mysql 8

Я в версии лары 5,7 использовал такой же подход все работало и при создании сущности, и при обновлении.

Comment: а есть куски из кода?

Comment: @Shokhaa Ну по сути последний метод это и есть тот кусок, конкретно какой код нужно выложить ?